# Visualforce : jQuery Datepicker not showing

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I am attempting to use jQuery to show datepicker on a VF page. I used an HTML5 input tag before and that worked in chrome but not in IE. If there are better ways to show the calendar in both chrome and IE please feel free to give me your solution.

todate and fromDate are both public string variables with setter and getters

```
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'css/jquery-ui.min.css')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'js/jquery.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'js/jquery-ui.min.js')}"/>
    <script>
      $j = jQuery.noConflict();

      $j(document).ready(function($) {
      $j('[id$=datepickerFrom]').datepicker("hide")
      $j('[id$=datepickerTo]').datepicker("hide")
      });
      function callDatePickerFrom()
      {
           $j('[id$=datepickerFrom]').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyy'})
      }
      function callDatePickerTo()
      {
         $j('[id$=datepickerTo]').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyy'})
      }
    </script>


  <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock>
    From Date:  <input value="{!fromDate}" id="datepickerFrom"  type="text" />   
    To Date: <input value="{!toDate}" id="datepickerTo" type="text" /> 
  </apex:form>
```

Comment: when you run `$j('[id$=datepickerFrom]')` in the browser console, does it show you the element from the page or does it find nothing?

Comment: Using `input` instead of `apex:input` means your controller can't read the values. Are you sure you meant to do this? If not, you should just do `$j('#datepickerFrom')`.

Answer (score 0):

In the below solution I have used `<apex:input type="date"` with JQuery datepicker. I kept the `<apex:input type="date"` fields hidden and used two html `<input type="text"` fields to display the date picker to the user. In background I used JavaScript to copy the date value back and forth. Hope this helps.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page id="myPage" docType="html-5.0" controller="JqueryDatePicker">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <apex:form id="myForm">
      From Date: <apex:input type="date" id="fromDate" value="{!fromDate}" style="display:none;" /> <input type="text" id="fromDatePicker"></input>
      To Date: <apex:input type="date" id="toDate" value="{!toDate}" style="display:none;" /> <input type="text" id="toDatePicker"></input>
      <apex:commandButton value="Show Dates" action="{!showDates}" rerender="myPage"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
              $j( "#fromDatePicker" ).datepicker({
                      altField: "#myPage\\:myForm\\:fromDate",
                      altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
               });
              $j( "#toDatePicker" ).datepicker({
                      altField: "#myPage\\:myForm\\:toDate",
                      altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
               });
               $j("#fromDatePicker").value($j("#myPage\\:myForm\\:fromDate").value());
               $j("#toDatePicker").value($j("#myPage\\:myForm\\:toDate").value());
      </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class JqueryDatePicker {
    public Date fromDate {get;set;}
    public Date toDate {get;set;}
    public JqueryDatePicker() {

    }
    public PageReference showDates() {
        System.debug('######### fromDate'+fromDate);
        System.debug('######### toDate'+toDate);
        return null;
    }

}
```